# Previewing data with meteor-autoform

Tags: javascript, validation, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have a tabbed page layout with a form and a preview. Is there any way to validate a form with pushing the 'Preview' button, and to switch to the second tab once it's valid? I.e. we are not creating anything until the 'Submit' button is pressed.

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane text-left fade in active" id="compose">
        {{#autoForm collection="Jobs" id="insertJobForm" type="insert"}}
            {{> afQuickField name="title" class="form-control input-lg"}}
            [more fields]
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit">Preview</button>
            </div>
        {{/autoForm}}
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane text-left" id="preview">
        <h2>{{currentFieldValue "title"}}</h2>
        [more output]
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the autoform's validation with `AutoForm.validateForm('yourFormIdGoesHere')` and extract the values with `Autoform.getFormValues(yourFormIdGoesHere)` or can simply serialise the form.

Then you use the values as the data context to the preview templates: `{{>previewTemplate formData}}`  you need to create a template helpers for this.